# Hibernate sorting entities increases version number of parent entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sorting, version

I came across hibernate behaviour which I find hard to understand and it would be great if someone can explain what is going on. First of all I'm using spring with hibernate.

I have some code like below, The reference "a" is an entity loaded from db,

```
List<C> cs = a.getB().getCs();
Collections.sort(cs);
```

The entity "C" implements Comparable. There's a @Transactional spring annotation on the method which calls this code. What I'm not really sure about is, when this sort happens I see an increase in version number of entity "B" if I comment out `Collections.sort(cs)` then it doesn't. It would make sense if it really changed the order of Cs in the list. However it doesn't really change the order because they are already sorted in the table and I get same result when I remove `Collections.sort(cs)`. So what is causing the increase in version number?

Am I missing something obvious? It would be good to know what causes this behaviour. I'll be happy to cook some code up if you want more details.

Comment: So you call `session.saveOrUpdate(a)` after sorting and then you see the increased version number in the database? Can you show your annotations for `getCs()`?

Comment: I use spring I've updated the question to reflect that. I don't explicitly call saveOrUpdate. But when I'm out of a method annotated with @transactional I reckon hibernate would check the state of the entity and if it's modified it should persist changes. There are no annotations on `getCs()` itself but there are annotations on entity "B" and entity "C", I can update the question with them if you want.

Comment: Well, you explicitly use a **list** - hence the order is important to you. Then you *change* the order. Of course that means the entity is updated. If order does not matter to you or you want to make changes to the collection without it being reflected in the entity - use a Set or create your own list out of the contents of this one.

Comment: @Ordous Yes you are right in the sense it didn't have to be a list. However as I said, the order hasn't changed after the sort. They are still in the same order as they are in DB after the sort operation. But when sorting, each C in list would have been moved to different index positions which could explain this behaviour??

Comment: @opensourcegeek I imagine that this has to do with [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-indexed). Hibernate has use of positions of elements in a List - using an index column. As it helpfully states - if you wish to use List semantics but do not have an index column - use a bag

Comment: @Ordous If I change it to Set in entity mapping and then manually convert it into List then apply  Collections.sort hibernate won't increase the version number then?

Comment: @opensourcegeek Why don't you try it?

Comment: @Ordous That my friend is the right question :) I'll try it but I would have to isolate this code if I change the mapping type I won't be able to compile, it might take a while - but in meantime if there's someone who has gone through this path it would be good to get their insight.